# Syntax/Object issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to do this evolution thing with different characters and it is having an issue with the "if (perTable. + ("per" + per + 1) + .allele == "black")" part of the code. It throws unexpected identifier error whereas I thought everything was in the correct syntax. I'm new to code and would appreciate any easy fix for this.

I tried spreading out the plus signs by adding some spaces in between `perTable`, ("per" + per + 1) bit, and also before the .allele but that didn't seem to help either.

Code:

```
var per = 0;
var perTable = {
 per1: {
    allele: "green",
    number: "1",
    living:"1",
  },
  per2: {
    allele: "black",
    number: "2",
    living:"1",
  }
};
// console.log(perTable.per2.number)

 for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(perTable).length; i++){
  //  console.log("per"+(per + 1))
  if (perTable. + ("per" + per + 1) + .allele == "black"){
    console.log("okay");
  } else {
    console.log("yikes");
  }

   per++;
 };
```

I want it to log "okay" once and "yikes" once in console but instead I get unexpected identifier at line 19 and letter 16. If you could help that would be great!

Comment: Use object bracket notation for the `["per" + (per + 1)]` part .. note the `()` so `per + 1` is a number, otherwise the whole thing will be treated as strings as if you typed `"per" + per.toString() + "1"`

Comment: I did that and it still said Unexpected Identifier.

Comment: so you did exactly `perTable["per" + (per + 1)].allele`

Answer (score 1):

This is not a correct javascript syntax. But there's a way to get sub-elements dynamically.

Instead of accessing it with dots `.`, you will want to access it with `[]`, like this :

```
if (perTable["per" + (per + 1)].allele == "black"){
```

This notation will allow you to access the sub-element dynamically.

**Note** that I added parenthesis around "per +1", because since you are adding string and integers, Javascript will concat the stirng representation of `per` and `1`, meaning you would have `per01` and `per11` instead of `per1` and `per2`

Comment: you don't need the outer `()` :p

Comment: Nice catch, corrected it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't access dynamic properties using [dot notation, use bracket notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets).

Now your datastructure is flawed by itself. Either you want to access it by index, then use an array, or you need key-value pairs, then don't try to compose keys in a loop. Instead use either `Object.keys`, `Object.values` or `Object.entries` to work with them:

```
 for(const obj of Object.values(perTable)) {
   if(obj.allele) { /*...*/ } else { /*...*/ }
 }
```

Comment: @jaromanda oh wow, either my keyboard did not react or I need sleep :)

Comment: This is definitely the superior solution by iterating over the object directly.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Line 18 is causing the error:

```js
perTable. + ("per" + per + 1) + .allele
```

There are [two ways](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) to access properties in JavaScript object: Dot notation and bracket notation

```js
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2}
// Dot notation
console.log(obj.a) // 1
// Bracket notation
console.log(obj['a']) // 1
```

In this case, bracket notation would work better

```js
perTable["per" + (per + 1)].allele
```

Here's the full snippet!

```js
var per = 0;
var perTable = {
  per1: {
    allele: "green",
    number: "1",
    living:"1",
  },
  per2: {
    allele: "black",
    number: "2",
    living:"1",
  }
};
// console.log(perTable.per2.number)

for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(perTable).length; i++){
  //  console.log("per"+(per + 1))
  if (perTable["per" + (per + 1)].allele == "black"){
    console.log("okay");
  } else {
    console.log("yikes");
  }

  per++;
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Most likely the browser is complaining about this: `perTable. + ("per"...` because the `.` here makes no sense. It looks like you are attempting to build an object key from the value of a variable. When you do this, you can no longer use dot notation. Instead you need to use bracket notation:

```
perTable["per" + per + 1]
```

Note that in situations like this it is often helpful to break a long expression into smaller assignments statements. For example (using your original attempt):

```
key = "per" + per + 1;
allele = perTable. + key + .allele
if (allele == "black") {
...
```

This helps show where the problem is because the error will point at the line `allele =`. Also, it makes the code easier to read when you come back to look at it later.

Comment: that would be `perTable.per01` if `per === 0`

Comment: yes, sorry, but your first code is still wrong for the reason in the first comment

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm only fixing the syntax error here. I'm not going to spend the time fixing all of the logic errors.

Comment: so, you're not helping?

Comment: @JaromandaX Besides, there are better ways of iterating over the keys of an object.